# Ubuntu 14.04 is totally broken, how can I reinstall from a new disk?

Tags: unity, kernel, compiz, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I tried updating my kernel (intel pentium processor, Msi r7 260x graphics, Ubuntu 14.04) and now my computer will boot and display a black screen and a pop up saying the stored configuration for monitors could not be applied and that the requested is (3840,1080) (I have two monitors) and the max is (1920,1920). I can load the Ctrl alt f1 terminal but everything I have tried has not worked. I am not an incredibly seasoned Linux user so I do not know what to do. Can I do a fresh reinstall?

Comment: Can you still successfully boot with an older kernel?  Fix the display problem there maybe?

Comment: When I hold shift and load the grub I've tried 5-6 random ones and none work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1917220
Try removing ~/.config/monitors.xml

---

monitors.xml is a file, not a package. Remove it from a terminal with the rm command:

```
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Comment: Tried this, my computer was "unable to locate package /home/myname/.config" and "couldn't find any package by regex '/home/myname/.config'

Comment: rm: Cannot remove '/home/username/.config/monitors.xml': no such file or directory. Any ideas? Thank you for the help thus far.

Comment: Actually, now on boot instead of the monitors issue I get: System program problem detected.

Comment: rsk997: Could you please post the output of the back-up of your monitors.xml file into your question?  Maybe one of the configurations it contains is bad.  Removing that should remove the problem...  Don't remove the entire file...